# Format XML String to Friendly XML String with highlighting

Tags: c#, xml, string, formatting, syntax-highlighting

I use this to format a XML String to Print Friendly XML String

```
public static string PrintXML(string xml)
{
    string result = "";

    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(mStream, Encoding.Unicode);
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

    try
    {
        // Load the XmlDocument with the XML.
        document.LoadXml(xml);

        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        // Write the XML into a formatting XmlTextWriter
        document.WriteContentTo(writer);
        writer.Flush();
        mStream.Flush();

        // Have to rewind the MemoryStream in order to read
        // its contents.
        mStream.Position = 0;

        // Read MemoryStream contents into a StreamReader.
        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(mStream);

        // Extract the text from the StreamReader.
        string formattedXml = sReader.ReadToEnd();

        result = formattedXml;
    }
    catch (XmlException)
    {
        // Handle the exception
    }

    mStream.Close();
    writer.Close();

    return result;
}
```

this is working really fine. But I have one problem and would like to highlight a part of my XML content.

The problem is the following: 
my string contains a header like this: **STP/00/276/**

so:

```
string s = ("STP/00/276/<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?><RequestResponse><RequestName>GetInfo</RequestName></Params></RequestResponse>")
```

How to solve that?

On the other hand, is it possible to change the color of the content?

So I would like to have this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<RequestResponse>
<RequestName>GetInfo</RequestName>
</Params>
</RequestResponse>
```

And "GetInfo" should be written in red f.e.

Comment: You can simply remove your header first, format the rest with the code that you already have, then add the header back to the formatted XML. This should be very easy. If your header cannot include the `<` character, then simply take all text up to the first `<` and that will be your header.

Comment: A side note, do not use parentheses around the value of the string variable. Why do you do that?

Comment: Use XmlWriterSettings and set property Ident = true to add returns to the data.

Comment: @jdweng sorry for this may stupid question, but how to use XmLWriterSettings?

Comment: XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
             XmlTextWriter tWriter = new XmlTextWriter(mStream, Encoding.Unicode);
             XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(tWriter, settings);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove your header first, format the rest with the code that you already have, then add the header back to the formatted XML. Something like this:

```
string s = "STP/00/276/<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?><RequestResponse><Params><RequestName>GetInfo</RequestName></Params></RequestResponse>";
int index = s.IndexOf("<?xml");
string header = s.Substring(0, index);
s = s.Substring(index);
s = header + "\r\n" + PrintXML(s);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qf4MiX).